# Jump to specific line in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

In x86 assembly language, is it possible to specify a jump to a specific line number? Here, I'm trying to use the `jmp` instruction to the line number 3. (I don't yet know of a way to pass a label as a parameter to a function, so I'm trying to use a line number instead of a label in this case.)

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048
.data

ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword
.code

start:

jmp 3; this produces the error shown below

mov ax, 0
mov bx, 0
mov ah, 1

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

The code above produces the error `1>p4.asm(11): error A2076: jump destination must specify a label`.

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to have a line 3.

Comment: It would, if the whitespace was counted.

Comment: But jumping to whitespace is meaningless, right?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @CarlNorum OK, I've fixed it- the program has a line 3 now.

Comment: So line 3 is `mov bx, 0`?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just put a label at that line.  Depending on your assembly language dialect, you might be be able to use a numeric local label, or you might need to use symbolic labels.  A possible example follows. I have only NASM here to test, so I'm not really sure this example will map well to MASM, but you should get the idea:

```
start:
    jmp .line3
    mov ax, 0
.line3:
    mov bx, 0
    mov ah, 1
```

NASM uses a leading `.` to identify local labels.

Comment: That might work. However, I still don't know of any way to pass a label as a parameter to a function in x86 assembly (and that's why I'm trying to use a number instead of a label).

Comment: @AndersonGreen, a label is usable pretty much as a pointer in most cases.

Comment: In that case, how could the label be passed as a parameter to a function?

Comment: That depends on the calling convention, but for ia32, pushing the appropriate address to the right spot on the stack will do it.  For x86_64, you'll want to put it in the appropriate register.  Something like `lea rcx, label`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s1:   add ax,1
      jmp $-3
```

this can make you program jump to the s1. Be careful,the number is the offset of code,not the number of line.( instruction 'add ax,1' is 3 bytes)
if you want to make a indirect jump,try this:

```
jmp far [address]
address dw 0123h ;the ip
        dw 5678h ;the cs
```

more imformation,google indirect jump.

Comment: In 16-bit code `add ax,1` is 3 bytes `83 c0 01`, but in 32-bit code it's 4 bytes `66 83 c0 01`. In 32-bit code `83 c0 01` disassembles as `add eax,1`. So in this case jumping in the middle of the `66 83 c0 01` instruction produces a valid instruction (`db 0x66` is a prefix), but gives a different instruction. In the rare case you really wanted to jump to an offset that's inside an instruction, it's best to encode the instruction yourself (`db 0x66, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x01`), so you know the precise encoding used.

Comment: It's a good habbit to use `bits 16`or `bits 32`,this can avoid the 0x66 problem.